# my desktop on Acer some shortcuts do not work

Tags: windows-7

I have an Acer cpu, about 3 weeks ago some of my short cuts on the desktop do not work, windows 7 pro 32 bit. Please help. I have tried to use a restore from back up I am a new user so I am not sure what to do next.

Maria Pepin

Comment: Definitions: CPU is the "central processing unit". It is one small part of the "computer", which is what you're actually talking about. Use the EDIT button to make your question more clear. We need to know WHAT shortcuts aren't working, what symptoms or evidence you have for them not working, what you expect them to do that they are not doing, what they are doing that you do not expect them to do, and other similar information so that we can grasp the nature of the problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your shortcuts still point to the right location. This can be done by right-clicking each of them and selection properties. In the link location field should be a valid location, e.g. it should point to the `.exe` of the specific application or whatever you want to link. You might copy the path in that field up to the last `\` into your windows explorer address bar and see if the file with the given name exists in that folder.

Of course, you can easily create new shortcuts on your desktop if the old ones don't work anymore (as long as you still have the original files you want to link to). In case of regular files, you can just right-click them and select `send to -> Desktop (Create Shortcut)` (or whatever it says in your language) to create a shortcut to that file on the desktop. In case of applications, you can search them in the windows start menu and right-click them there.

If this is about applications that are not installed anymore, you'd probably need to install them again. But for that, you'd need to provide additional information about your problem.